# Multiple AND/IFS in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently facing a problem if I add one more criteria to my formula. 
I created a tracker to measure a status below:

=IF((AND(A1<>"",B2<>"")),"Closed","Open")

What this does:
if A1 contains a value, and B2 is empty = Open
if both contain value = Closed
if both are empty = Open

I tried to insert one more criteria, but the formula doesn't work.

I am looking for a solution to return this:
If all are blank = Output 1
If A1 contains a value, B2 is blank and C2 is blank = Output 2
If A1 contains a value, B2 contains a value, C2 blank = Output 3
If all contain a value = Output 4

Apreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with nested `if()`:

```
=if(and(a1="",b2="",c2=""), output1,
    if(and(b2="", c2=""), output2,
       if(c2="", output3, output4)))
```

The logic goes as:

- The first condition tests if all three are blank.
- If not, the second condition tests for `b2` and `c2`.  If these are blank, then `a1` must not be (otherwise it would be caught by the first condition).
- The third only needs to check for `c2` to distinguish between `output3` and `output4`.

Comment: Aren't you missing the closing parenthesis for the calls to AND?